# Другая страница, если регистрация успешна

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите новичку.

Есть форма заполнения данными. Как послать пользователя на другую страницу, если регистрация прошла успешно?

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
Введите логин: <br>
<input type="text" name="login"><br>
Введите пароль:<br>
<input type="text" name="pas"><br>
Подтвердите пароль:<br>
<input type="text" name="pas_clear"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
</form>
```

и код который обрабатывает форму и заносит данные в базу:

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1.Проверка правильности заполнения формы //
//////////////////////////////////////////////
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $pas = trim($_POST['pas']);
    $pas_clear = trim($_POST['pas_clear']);
    if (!empty($login) && !empty($pas) && !empty($pas_clear) && $pas==$pas_clear){
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // 2. Проверка на наличия уже существования логина //
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //подключение к базе данных
include "blocks/db.php";
        $usr = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE login = '$login'");
        $total = mysql_result($usr, 0);
        if($total > 0){
            exit("Данные логин уже зарегистрирован, пожалуйста, выберите другой.");
        }elseif($total == 0){
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 3. Регистрируем и заносим в базу логин и пароль пользователя //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $usr = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (NULL, '$login', '$pas')";
            if (mysql_query($usr)) {
                echo "</H3>Регистрация прошла успешно</H3>";
                echo "<p>Ваш логин: ".$login."\n<br> Ваш пароль: ".$pas."\n<br>Запомните свои данные, а лучше запишите.</p>";
                }elseif(!$usr){
                exit ("Ошибка при добавлении данных - ".mysql_error());
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Собственно вопрос, как можно сделать так, что если все пользователем введено правильно, то  вот это

```
echo "</H3>Регистрация прошла успешно</H3>";
echo "<p>Ваш логин: ".$login."\n<br> Ваш пароль: ".$pas."\n<br>Запомните свои данные, а лучше запишите.</p>";`
```

выводилось на другой странице уже без формы, но в случае ошибки, например, не совпадает пароль, то вывести информацию об этом на этой же странице? Обработчик у меня на той странице, где и форма `<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">`

Помогите, пожалуйста, с пояснением, буду вам всем глубоко благодарен. На безопасность не смотрите, как раз пишу функцию для этого.

Comment: @NoProblems, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: У вас там кстати xss через $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] :) 
http://localhost/script.php/"><script>alert(/xss/)</script>
выведет на экран /xss/, так что экранируйте через htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($register==true) echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://my-site.ru">';
```

5 - это задержка в секундах.

Comment: огромное спасибо, помогло после регистрации попасть на другую страницу) только как вывести на эту страничку логин и пароль пользователя? и еще пришлось 
 if($total > 0){
            exit("Данные логин уже зарегистрирован, пожалуйста, выберите другой.");
   exit изменить на echo, так как если пароль уже занят, то с помощью exit информация выводилась на другой странице, сейчас уже все нормально) если можешь, еще скажи почему так? )

Comment: чтоб на новой странице отобразить логин и пароль, то можно передать их через сессию или можно к url в meta добавить get.

    url=http://my-site.ru?login=Vasya&pass=123412341234

на странице выводите:

   echo "Логин: ".$_GET['login']."<br />Пароль: ".$_GET['pass'];

А на счет exit... Не понял...

Comment: Да не за что! Просто примите ответ, если вас он устроил. (Слева от ответа галочка)

Comment: все работает, спасибо тебе)))
но есть одно НО... если регистрирую логин на английском, то в строке логин видно на английском, а если на русском, то вот, посмотри)
http://localhost/test/reg.php?login=%E2%E0%EB%E5%F0%E0&pas=123
тут логин ВАЛЕРА... это ничего страшного? не из-за кодировки какой-то?

Comment: если на результирующей странице так отображается, то да, из-за кодировки. А то что в url так пишется, то это нормально. В url не должно быть кириллицы. Можете сами посмотреть что творится в адресной строке браузера, когда, например, в поиске яндекса что-нибудь вбить по-русски :)

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: http://needUrl.com");
```

Но до вызова этой функции не должно быть ни одного вывода. Рекомендую использовать буфер.

Comment: а можно по подробней, пожалуйста?

Comment: в начеле страницы пишешь ob_start(); в конце echo ob_get_clean(); Есть вывод произойдет в конце выполнения скрипта. Т.е. header() можно будет использовать где угодно до "echo"

Answer (score 0):

для того чтобы не было выводов есть приколы с utf-8 сохраняйте все файлы utf-8 без БОМ!